# Get the value of disabled input using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to get value of a disabled (`disabled="disabled"`) `<input>` field, but it returns an empty string.

I have tried: `.Text`, `GetAttribute("value")`, but none of this works so far.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you tag it like this -

```
<input disabled="true" id='data'>
```

Your code should be -

```
WebElement.getAttribute("disabled")
```

or

```
WebElement.getAttribute("id")
```

Make sure your code is correct.

For this tag -

```
<input id="j_idt93:j_idt93" type="text" disabled="disabled" maxlength="2000" value="Pārtraukts">
```

To get the value attribute -

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt93:j_idt93")).getAttribute("value");
```

value must be `Pārtraukts`

If this does not work, you may have to use the JavaScript executor -

```
String value =  (String)((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("JavaScript query in here to return the value", "");
```

Your query should be -

```
return document.getElementById("j_idt93:j_idt93").getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: HTML code is <input id="j_idt93:j_idt93" type="text" disabled="disabled" maxlength="2000" value="Pārtraukts"> I'm trying to get the value attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The only option that worked for me...

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("*******"));
jsExecutor= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
String compareHolder = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return arguments[0].value", webElement);
```