# How to getText from a disabled input field in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

How can I get text from a disabled input field in Selenium Java?

Below is the HTML tag.

```
<input id="endDate" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength" data-ng-disabled="dateRange!=='Cm'" size="10" maxlength="10" data-ng-model="endDate" validate-date="" name="endDate" disabled=""/>
```

I'm looking for Selenium Java code to get the text value from that disabled input field.

I tried `getAttribute("disabled")`. But it is returning true. I tried `WebElement.getAttribute("id")`, but it is returning null value. None of it worked.

The value of that field will be generated dynamically. For example, if I select today the values will be populated as `SYSDATE`. For the yesterday value will be `SYSDATE-1`.

Comment: Have a look at this topic, as it looks like the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429070/selenium-wd-get-value-of-disabled-input

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
webElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("#endDate")).getAttribute("value")
```

Or:

```
webElement.findElement(By.cssSelector("#endDate")).getText()
```

You have to try it out. It depends on your special case. If these variants don't work, check if your selectors are correct.

If all of them didn't work, try to get the value over *angular.element* as below:

```
return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) this.webDriver).executeScript("angular.element($('#endDate')).text()");
```

Comment: Thank youг so much!