# How to get the data from disabled drop down using selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Sample image with disabled drop down:
[image: Sample image with disabled drop down]

**tried:**

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(dropDownLocator));
List<WebElement> all_Options=select.getOptions();
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What was the result of this? What is the expected result?

Comment: Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(dropDownLocator));
List<WebElement> all_Options=select.getOptions();

Comment: getting value as ""

Comment: Please add that along with the html for the image to the question itself, using the appropriate code blocks. Otherwise it's gonna be hard for us to help you

Comment: Instead of adding an image, please add the text of the HTML to the question. One day that image will no longer be available and then this question will be much less useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium WD - get value of disabled input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429070/selenium-wd-get-value-of-disabled-input)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='jobName']")); 
List<WebElement> all_Options = select.findElements(By.tagName("option");

string val1 = all_Options[0].getText();
```

Comment: you get empty select object ?

Comment: No i am getting an select object with size as 5.. but i am getting value as empty

Comment: try to look in debug mode what values you get for all_Optionsp[0]

Comment: you mean all_Options.get(0) ??