# How to getText from the disabled input field in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Not able to get Text from the disabled input field in selenium java. I tried:

`element.getAttribute("disabled")` ==> it returns True.

`element.getText()` ==> it returns Null

`(String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("angular.element($('#indirectRate')).text()")`==> it returns null too.

Here is the html:

```
    <input type="text" id="indirectRate" class="form-control 
ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty 
ng-valid-valdr-digits ng-valid-valdr-min ng-valid-valdr-max ng-valid-valdr" 
 name="indirectRate" ng-model="proposal.budget.indirectRate" ng- 
 disabled="proposalElementDisabled() || proposal.budget.indirectType === 
 'DISALLOWED'" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: <input type="text" id="indirectRate" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-valdr-digits ng-valid-valdr-min ng-valid-valdr-max ng-valid-valdr" name="indirectRate" ng-model="proposal.budget.indirectRate" ng-disabled="proposalElementDisabled() || proposal.budget.indirectType === 'DISALLOWED'" disabled="disabled">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Selenium Web Driver to retrieve value of a HTML input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852287/using-selenium-web-driver-to-retrieve-value-of-a-html-input)

Comment: Rather than putting important information in the comments, edit your question and add the HTML (and any other relevant info) there instead. This prevents future readers from having to read all the comments to get all the relevant bits to answer the question.

Comment: @Yani There can't be any _text_ as such in an `<input>` tag but there can be _placeholder_ text. Are you trying to extract the _value_ of any attribute? Which _attribute_?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
element.getAttribute("value")
```

"innerHTML" and "input" texts are handled differently in selenium.

Comment: Yes, element.getAttribute("value") works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using `value`

1. `element.getAttribute("value")`

or you can try getting the value over angular element

2. `return (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) this.webDriver).executeScript("angular.element($('#indirectRate')).text()");`

You can find more information in this thread:
[Selenium WD - get value of disabled input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429070/selenium-wd-get-value-of-disabled-input)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```